# How to check how many times the clock has shown a full hour between two dates?

Tags: swift, date

I want to check how many **full calendar hours** have passed between two dates.

15:00 -> 15:00 = 0 Hours

15:00 -> 16:00 = 1 Hour

15:30 -> 16:15 = 1 Hour

16:45 -> 18:10 = 2 Hours

I **don`t** want to know the total hours that you can get with:

```
Calendar.current.dateComponents([.hour], from: date, to: date2).hour
```

Any ideas how to do this?

Comment: For the sake of future readers (or potential answers) you could try to describe your problem more clearly. Is *"how many times does the clock show a full hour between the two dates"*  what you are looking for? – What if both dates fall on a full hour, i.e. "15:00 -> 16:00"? Is 1 or 2 the expected result? And for "15:00 -> 15:00" ?

Comment: Yeah that would be a better title. 15:00 -> 16:00 should be 1 and  15:00 -> 15:00 = 0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First compute the *start of the hour* for both dates:

```
let start1 = cal.dateInterval(of: .hour, for: date1)?.start
let start2 = cal.dateInterval(of: .hour, for: date2)?.start
```

Use these to compute the difference in hours, as before.

Full self-contained example:

```
let cal = Calendar.current
let date1 = DateComponents(calendar: cal, year: 2018, month: 6, day: 15, hour: 16, minute: 45).date!
let date2 = DateComponents(calendar: cal, year: 2018, month: 6, day: 15, hour: 18, minute: 10).date!

let start1 = cal.dateInterval(of: .hour, for: date1)!.start
let start2 = cal.dateInterval(of: .hour, for: date2)!.start

let hours = cal.dateComponents([.hour], from: start1, to: start2).hour!
print(hours) // 2
```

Comment: Clean and simple. Thank you

Comment: This solution will produce "1" for an interval like 15:55 -> 16:01. Meaning that a whole hour has elapsed when in fact it's only been 6 minutes between the intervals. That might not be what you want depending on the circumstances.

Comment: @BellAppLab: You are right, but that's how I understand the question, given the two examples and the remark that `Calendar.current.dateComponents([.hour], from: date, to: date2).hour` is *not* what he wants.

Comment: Only the OP knows that. `¯\_(ツ)_/¯`

Comment: @BellAppLab: I'll try to clarify the question.

Comment: What about dates that are on different days? (For example from 12:00 today until 14:12 tomorrow.) Shouldn't the result for that be 26?

Comment: When you say "Use these to compute the difference in hours, as before" you mean use `Calendar.dateComponents([.hour],from:,to:)` to calculate the number of hours between start1 and start2?

Comment: @DuncanC: Yes, that's what I meant.

Comment: So your `cal.dateInterval(of: .hour, for: date1)?.start` is a quick-and-dirty way to get the "top of the hour" value for a given date? Cute trick, but seems like there should be a cleaner, more intuitive way to do that.

Comment: @DuncanC: `cal.date(from: cal.dateComponents([.era, .year, .month, .day, .hour], from: date1))!` would also work, but that requires to list (and to know) all those components. There might be a better solution, but I am currently not aware of it.

Comment: For either approach, wrapping it in an extension to Calendar with the function `func topOfHourFor(date: Date)` would be helpful and make for more self-documenting code.

Comment: @DuncanC: I'm just demonstrating the general idea, so everybody can decide for him/herself how to encapsulate it. There are also 3rd party libraries which already offer such computations, for example https://github.com/malcommac/SwiftDate has a `startOf(component:)` method.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at the `DateComponentsFormatter`. More specifically, you might want to do something like this:

```
let formatter = DateComponentsFormatter()
formatter.unitsStyle = .full
formatter.includesApproximationPhrase = false
formatter.includesTimeRemainingPhrase = false
formatter.allowedUnits = [.hour]

let string = formatter.string(from: date, to: date2) //prints out "2 hours"
```

[Source](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/datecomponentsformatter)

Comment: That would print "0 Hours", and not the expected result "1 Hour" for the interval 15:30 -> 16:15 given in the question.

Comment: Well... The interval 15:30 -> 16:15 is not a full hour. So that's technically correct.